# Adding Relationships and Navigation Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I go configuring or mapping the navigation property?

I have Employee table and currently it does display correctly `EmployeeStatusId` but what I would like to have the `EmployeeStatus` `Text` along with the `EmployeeStatusId` how would I handle this?

I have the following model:

Employee.cs

```
 public class Employee
 {
        [Key]
        public int? RecordId { get; set; }
        public string company{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeStatusId { get; set; }
 }
```

EmployeeStatus:

```
public class EmployeeStatus
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public class DataCenterDB : DbContext
{       
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeStatus> EmployeeStatus { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeStatus>().ToTable("EmployeeStatus");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.EmployeeStatus.Name)
```

This will get the the EmployeeStatus Name value for your model. As long as your relations are correct Entity Framework will automatically link them.

In your model

```
public class Employee
 {
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string company{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public int EmployeeStatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeStatus EmployeeStatus {get;set;}
 }

public class EmployeeStatus
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I used the keyword virtual in the class so it knows to link Employee entity to the EmployeeStatus entity.
Also if it's a foreign key relationship the EmployeeStatus ID should not be nullable

Comment: but don't you have to define the relationship or mapping?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: don't i have to define the reference? have a look at here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Yes do you see how they use the virtual keyword? That defines the relationship in the context

Comment: Also your ID properties shouldn't be nullable

Comment: yes i removed the nullable and i'm running into error... i will have to debug why i'm getting error "EmployeeStatusId": invalid identifier

Comment: Do you have data in the database?

Comment: yes i do have data in the db, how would you query this is what i am doing
`var model = new EmployeeViewModel = _db.Employees.Take(500).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should define `EmployeeStatus` property this way:

```
public class Employee
{
    // other properties

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeStatusId")]
    public virtual EmployeeStatus EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeStatusId { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeStatus
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside your controller action method you should populate a list of `EmployeeStatus`:

```
ViewBag.StatusList = new SelectList(_statusService.GetAllStatus(), "Id", "Name");
```

Finaly in your view you can this this code for displaying data inside a drop down:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeStatusId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeStatusId", (SelectList)ViewBag.StatusList, "-- Select ---", new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeStatusId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1+ I do not think you need to define Foreignkey unless you are working with code first approach